# Function to get row Value of a dataframe using str Index

Tags: python, pandas

Sample df:

```
Student  Marks
Avery     70
Joe       80
John      75
Jordan    90
```

I want to use a function as below to return marks when a student name is passed.

```
def get_marks(student):
    return *something*
```

Expected Output: get_marks('Joe') ==> 80

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might work.

```python
def get_marks(student):
    p = df.index[df['Student'] == student].tolist()
    p = p[0]
    return df['Marks'][p]
```

What I have done is I have first to get the index of row of the Student and then simply return the Marks for the same index.